Messaging for In-App and Web :- chat always inactive between agent in omni channel and chatbot
I have set up Messaging for In-App and Web in Salesforce, including Messaging Configuration, Embedded Service Deployment, Queue, and Routing Configuration. When a message is sent through the chatbot, the agent can accept the request, and a messaging session is created between the chatbot and the agent in the Omni-Channel widget. However, the agent is unable to send messages to the chatbot, and no messages from the chatbot appear in the conversation tab of the Messaging session.

What need to be done to make active chat where both can communicate


You need to edit the lightning page layout and add the component "Enhanced Converation". You may also need to ensure regular page layouts are created for Messaging Session and Messaging User and are correctly assigned.
